# How to copy file to another folder and remove the file

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml

I used below code and get error message:

{"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."}

If I use this, it will work provided there is no similiar file exits.

await targetFile.CopyAsync(folder, strfilenm);

```
public static async void CopyTheFile(StorageFolder Subfdl, string strfilenm)
        {
            string strPath = "C:\\Users\\XYZUser\\Documents\\MyStuffBU";

            StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(strPath);
            var targetFile = await Subfdl.GetFileAsync(strfilenm);

            await targetFile.CopyAndReplaceAsync(targetFile);            
            await targetFile.DeleteAsync();     

        }
```

How to do this:

copy the file from the current folder (in C:) and to another folder (in C:) even there could be similar filename exits 
later, remove the file in the current folder

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to replace the file with a copy of itself with this line:

```
await targetFile.CopyAndReplaceAsync(targetFile);
```

See the documentation of [CopyAndReplaceAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738482).

You should use [MoveAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227217) or one of it's overrides. This way you won't have to call DeleteAsync neither, since the file will be moved.